# Node.js Middleware to check if a user is following another user

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to write a middleware that checks if a user is currently following another user or not. I am using Nodejs and MySQL.

I did something like this but it doesn't seem to work (I used if(result.length) because if the current user is not following anyone I get an error because there is no follower_id in the data).

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
   var q ="SELECT * FROM follows WHERE follower_id ='" + req.user.id + "'";
   connection.query(q, function(err, result){
      if(err) throw err;
      if (result.length > 0){
      res.locals.isFollowing = result;
      next();  
      }
   });
});
```

My follows table is:

```
+-------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field       | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+-------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| follower_id | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
| followee_id | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
| created_at  | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
+-------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
Data 
+-------------+-------------+---------------------+
| follower_id | followee_id | created_at          |
+-------------+-------------+---------------------+
|           1 |           2 | 2018-02-02 01:22:24 |
|           1 |          12 | 2018-02-02 01:24:34 |
+-------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

I will be using this middleware throughout the website to check if a user is currently following or not (e.g post page, profile page..etc) 
I don't even know if what I am currently doing is the right approach to do such a thing.

Comment: `if(err) throw err;` is NEVER appropriate async error handling.  You would just end up with the current request hanging, never sending a response and eventually, some number of minutes later, the browser would timeout.  If the request is hosed at that point, returns a 5xx status and end the request.

Comment: You have to understand the result you're getting back from the database and send the code down the right path for all possible results.  If a particular error means they are not following them, then your code needs to check for that specific condition and do the right thing in the middleware if that's the case.  We probably can't help with specifics because we don't know the whole layout of your database, but you can see what is returned for various conditions with your own testing and then code for that..